# LambdaJ for GWT

Tags: gwt, lambdaj

my application workes heavily with collections and I have to find out an effecient way to work with them insted of looping through them all the time.

I learnt that LambdaJ cannot be used in GWT. then what is the equivalent that can be used for GWT?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)? It is usable with GWT. Its Strings and Collections libraries are quite helpful.